# regex to parse import statements in python

Tags: python, regex

can someone help me writing **single** regex to get module(s) from python source line?

```
from abc.lmn import pqr
from abc.lmn import pqr as xyz
import abc
import abc as xyz
```

it has 3 sub parts in it

```
[from(\s)<module>(\s)] --> get module if this part exist
import(\s)<module>     --> get module
[(\s)as(\s)<alias>]    --> ignore if this part exist
```

something like this

```
:?[from(\s)<module>(\s)]import(\s)<module>:?[(\s)as(\s)<alias>]
```

Comment: You should base it on [the grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you could make the *from* optional and the *import* required at
the same time ignoring the *as*.

`(?m)^(?:from[ ]+(\S+)[ ]+)?import[ ]+(\S+)[ ]*$`

https://regex101.com/r/fmoAuh/1

Explained

```
 (?m)                          # Modifiers: multi-line
 ^                             # Beginning of line
 (?:                           # Optional from
      from [ ]+ 
      ( \S+ )                       # (1), from <module>
      [ ]+ 
 )?

 import [ ]+                   # Required import
 ( \S+ )                       # (2), import <module>
 [ ]* 
 $                             # End of line
```

---

Or, if you want to match the *as* but do not want to capture anything, use this.

`(?m)^(?:from[ ]+(\S+)[ ]+)?import[ ]+(\S+)(?:[ ]+as[ ]+\S+)?[ ]*$`

https://regex101.com/r/xFtey5/1

Expanded

```
 (?m)                          # Modifiers: multi-line
 ^                             # Beginning of line
 (?:                           # Optional from
      from [ ]+ 
      ( \S+ )                       # (1), from <module>
      [ ]+ 
 )?

 import [ ]+                   # Required import
 ( \S+ )                       # (2), import <module>

 (?:                           # Optional as
      [ ]+ 
      as [ ]+ 
      \S+                          # <alias>
 )?
 [ ]* 
 $
```

Answer (score 23):

Instead of using a regex, using the built in python library ast might be a better approach.  https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html  You can use it to parse python syntax.

```
import ast

import_string = """from abc.lmn import pqr
from abc.lmn import pqr as xyz
import abc
import abc as xyz"""

modules = []
for node in ast.iter_child_nodes(ast.parse(import_string)):
    if isinstance(node, ast.ImportFrom):
        if not node.names[0].asname:  # excluding the 'as' part of import
            modules.append(node.module)
    elif isinstance(node, ast.Import): # excluding the 'as' part of import
        if not node.names[0].asname:
            modules.append(node.names[0].name)
```

that will give you ['abc.lmn', 'abc'] and it is fairly easy to tweak if you want to pull other information.

Comment: Might be a good idea to use `ast.walk` if you want to find import statements not at the toplevel.

Comment: great nice idea

Comment: Great answer. However, this code fails to capture multiple imports, such as "import a, b, c, d". Instead of just using node.names[0], you should iterate over all node.names.