# Regex to capture all import statements

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, negative-lookbehind

I want to create a script that looks inside a Python file and finds all `import` statements. Possible variations of those are the following:

```
import os
import numpy as np
from itertools import accumulate
from collections import Counter as C
from pandas import *
```

---

By looking at these, one could argue that the logic should be:

*Get me all `<foo>` from `from <foo>` statements and those `<bar>` from `import <bar>` that are not preceded by `from <foo>`.*

To translate the above in regex, I wrote:

```
from (\w+)|(?<!from \w+)import (\w+)
```

The problem seems to be with the non-fixed width of the negative lookbehind but I cannot seem to be able to fix it.

EDIT:

As a bonus, it would also be nice to capture multiple includes as in:

```
import sys, glob
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to only get them at the start of a line? `^(?:from\s+(\w+)|import\s+(\w+))`? Or even `^(?:from|import)\s+(\w+)` (not sure you want to differentiate between the two types)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Not necessarily. They might be inside functions or classes or if statements, etc. and thus indented.

Comment: Ok, but that also means you may have `s="""this is a present from me"""` and it will also get matched. Moreover, there are `import re, csv, pandas` like imports.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew [Why would that get matched?](https://regex101.com/r/dadbF2/1). Oh yeah, I need that too. Thanks!

Comment: i think your problem is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44988487/regex-to-parse-import-statements-in-python

Comment: [Because you do not want to only match at the start](https://regex101.com/r/dadbF2/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I see. We could easily modify it to look only for whitespace before though, right?

Comment: Do you mean `^\s*(?:from|import)\s+(\w+)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/QVt56S/1))?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Exactly. I would accept that as an answer if you feel comfortable enough posting it. Thanks btw!

Comment: But what about `import re, csv,  pandas`?  Maybe `^\s*(?:from|import)\s+(\w+(?:\s*,\s*\w+)*)` will be better? See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/QVt56S/2). You will need to post-process the match then, though.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it keeps getting better..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you only want to extract the matches from the start of a line, taking into account the leading whitespace.

You may consider using

```
^\s*(?:from|import)\s+(\w+(?:\s*,\s*\w+)*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QVt56S/2).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string  (use `re.M` to also match start of a line)
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces (use `[^\S\r\n]*` to only match horizontal whitespace)
- `(?:from|import)` - either of the two words
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(\w+(?:\s*,\s*\w+)*)` - 1 or more word chars, followed with 0+ occurrences of 0+ whitespaces, `,`, 0+ whitespaces and then 1+ word chars.

In Python, you may later split the Group 1 value with `re.split(r'\s*,\s*', group_1_value)` to get individual comma-separated module names.